# How to move PointCloud to coordinates center?

Tags: swift, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a PointCloud which have points with position(x, y, z) and color(r, g, b)
But points lays in big distance from coordinates canter:
[image]

Question is: what algorithm can be used to place all points to coordinates center? My guess is to create translation matrix and multiply all pointCloud points to it, but I can't determine what this matrix should contain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer. Need to find center of mass of PointCloud with something like this:

```
    var summX: Float = 0
    var summY: Float = 0
    var summZ: Float = 0

    for point in points {
        summX += point.x
        summY += point.y
        summZ += point.z
    }

    let middleX = summX / Float(points.count)
    let middleY = summY / Float(points.count)
    let middleZ = summZ / Float(points.count)

    let centerOfMass = Float3(x: middleX, y: middleY, z: middleZ)
```

Then create translation matrix

[image]

And finally multiply all points to this matrix

```
    let translationMatrix = float4x4(simd_float4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: -centerOfMass.x),
                                     simd_float4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: -centerOfMass.y),
                                     simd_float4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: -centerOfMass.z),
                                     simd_float4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1))

    let translatedPoints = points.map { point in
        return point * translationMatrix
    }
```